# Getting TypeError: any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given while running python code

Tags: python, pandas

Getting this below error while running python code.
**line 194, in 
df2 = Degi_Manu[pd.DataFrame(Degi_Manu.loc[:,'System(s)']).isin(list(set(q1))).any(1)]
TypeError: any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

```
df2 = Degi[pd.DataFrame(Degi.loc[:,'System(s)']).isin(list(set(q1))).any(1)]
df2['PMT'] = 'PMT '+str(num)
result = result.append(df2)
```

Can someone pls help in this

Comment: Try using `any` with the keyword argument `axis`, i.e., `df2 = Degi[pd.DataFrame(Degi.loc[:,'System(s)']).isin(list(set(q1))).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `DataFrame` constructor with `loc` and `any`:

```
df2 = Degi[Degi['System(s)'].isin(list(set(q1)))]
```

In your code is used `any` for convert one column `DataFrame` to `Series`, which is necesary for correct filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

If there are duplicated columns called `System(s)`, so `Degi['System(s)']` return `DataFrame` is necessary add `any` with keyword `axis=1`:

```
df2 = Degi[Degi['System(s)'].isin(list(set(q1))).any(axis=1)]
```